# I'm developing a vs-code extension, which api to use for displaying error message in the same line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image with error msg in line no: 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUu9m.png)

I'm developing a vs code extension, I need to display error msg in a specified line, like the one in the image (*undeclared name: adf*, in red color). Could someone help me with which api to use. I read the documentation, but couldn't find which api to use to achieve this.

Comment: you have to create `Diagnostic` objects, search the api page for this

Comment: I would also suggest `Diagnostic` instead of `Decoration` that is suggested in duplicity question. 
Vscode has nice samples:
[Diagnostic implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/diagnostic-related-information-sample/src/extension.ts),
[All samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples)

Comment: @PetrSpacek this is what I'am looking for - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/diagnostic-related-information-sample/src/extension.ts, thanks.